# ¿Cómo puedo comparar 2 arrays?

Tags: java, array

Bueno sucede lo siguiente, tengo un proyecto que hace una consulta a una tabla dentro de una base de datos, esa base de datos tiene una columna con nombre "REPORTES" y cuando encuentra una fila con la columa "REPORTES" = 0 la añade a una JTable que tengo en mi programa y suena una alarma.
en cada fila que aparece dentro de mi JTable aparece un botón (APAGAR) el cual cumple con la función de apagar la alarma, con la única condición de que todos los botones de apagar hayan sido presionados.
EJEMPLO:
[image: EJEMPLO]

Para poder apagar la alarma tendría que presionar los 5 botones de APAGAR, que aparecen dentro de la tabla.

cabe destacar que el programa hace la misma consulta a base de datos cada 60 segundo. Y es aquí donde surge el problema, ya que al momento de volver a hacer la consulta las alarmas que ya había apagado suenan de nuevo, cuando no deberían sonar, ya que se supone que se encuentran apagadas.
Lo que se me ocurrió para corregir este problema fue almacenar en un array los ID de las alarmas que ya tengo apagadas, y al momento de hacer la consulta guardar en otro array el id de las alarmas que voy a traer, de esta forma poder hacer una comparación de que si ambos array son completamente iguales, (tienen los mismos valores) la alarma suene, pero si se agrega un valor nuevo no suene, ejemplo:

ID[] = {1,2,3,4,5} y alarmasApagadas[] = {1,2,3,4,5} = no suena.

ID[] = {1,2,3,4,5,6} y alarmasApagadas[] = {1,2,3,4,5} = suena.

a continuación dejo la función de comparación que hice, la cual obviamente no funciona:

```
 public void comparación() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException{    
    if(Arrays.equals(nuevosID, alarmasApagadas)){
        System.out.println("SON IGUALES");
    }else{
    try {
            play();//Función que reproduce la alarma.
        } catch (UnsupportedAudioFileException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
    
}
```

Este es el evento en donde voy agregando elementos a mi array de alarmas apagadas:

```
 private void tableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                   

   int column = table.getColumnModel().getColumnIndexAtX(evt.getX());
   int row = evt.getY()/table.getRowHeight();
   
   if(row < table.getRowCount() && row >= 0 && column < table.getColumnCount() && column >=0){
   
   Object value = table.getValueAt(row, column);
   if(value instanceof JButton){
   ((JButton)value).doClick();
   JButton boton = (JButton) value;
   
     seleccion();//Función que trae los valores de las columnas seleccionadas.
   
   if(boton.getName().equals("A")){//Botón apagar
       
   if(!instancia){
           alarmasApagadas = new int[getAlarmas()+1];
           instancia = true;
   }
       
       int idtabla = Integer.parseInt(getIdTabla());
   
            if(buscarLista(alarmasApagadas,idtabla)){ //Función que busca dentro del array para evitar que el botón sea usado mas de 1 vez.

       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Esta alarma ya se encuentra apagada","ALARMA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
       }else{
        
       String mensaje = "Realmente desea apagar la alarma para el registro\n" + "con Fecha: " + getFechaTabla() + 
                        "\nDel centro: " + getCentroTabla() + " Caja: " + getCajaTabla();
       
      int resp = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(rootPane, mensaje, "APAGAR ALARMA",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
      
      if(resp == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION){
         
          mensaje = "Se ha detenido la alarma del registro con fecha: " +getFechaTabla()+
                    "\n Del centro: " + getCentroTabla() + " Caja: " + getCajaTabla();
         
          /*Si el número de veces que se ha apagado la alarma es igual al número de alarmas*/
          if(clic == getAlarmas()){
              
          /*Detiene la alarma*/
          detener();
          
          /*Instancia el número de clics a uno*/
          clic = 1;
          
          }else{/*Si no aumenta el número de clics de alarmas apagadas en 1*/
          clic++;
          }
          
          sec.mostrarSeccionInformacion(secInfo,mensaje);
         
          alarmasApagadas[getPosicion()] = idtabla;
          posicion++;

       }
      
      }
          
   }if(boton.getName().equals("F")){//Botón que hace aparecer un modal
 
   modal();//este modal hace un update a base de datos.
   DefaultTableModel modelo = (DefaultTableModel) table.getModel();
    modelo.removeRow(table.getSelectedRow());
   
   }
   
   }
   }
    
}
```

Este es el código que se ejecuta cada 60 segundos:

```
  @Override
public void run() {
    
     while(!stop){
       try {
            actualizarTabla();
           p.setVisible(true);
           
    
    if(db.getSinErrores()){
    String Mensaje = "Sin registros de pánico encontrados";
    sec.mostrarSeccionInformacion(p.secInfo,Mensaje);
    }  
    else
    {

    p.setPosicion(1);
    if(!comparar){
    p.play(); //Hace sonar la alarma
    comparar = true;
    }else if(comparar){
    p.comparación(); //Función que hace la comparación (que no funciona)
    }
    }
           
       } catch (SQLException | LineUnavailableException | IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | InterruptedException ex) {
           Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
           
       }
       
       try{
       Thread.sleep(60000);
       } catch (InterruptedException e) {
       }
   
       p.detener();//detiene la alarma
   
   }
    
}
```

de antemano agradecería mucho su ayuda. Solo necesito hacer una comparación de 2 arrays.

Comment: ¿Que indicativo te da de que no está funcionando? ¿Puedes añadir un ejemplo mostrando con qué arrays no te funciona?

Comment: @Gabitohh quizá esta funcionando, pero no esta funcionando como yo quiero, ya que en todo momento me devuelve un false, ósea, que a pesar de que nunca cambio la tabla dentro de la base de datos, (se mantiene siempre igual) me debería devolver true, ya que ambos array son lo mismo, ósea, en ningún momento añadí un ID nuevo.

Answer (score 1):

Si queres comparar 2 Arrays para ver si tienen el mismo contenido puedes crear un metodo que retorne un numero o un boolean y que reciba los 2 array como parámetros.
Array tiene un método que compara, por lo cual no haría falta crear el procedimiento, pero si queres hacerlo por prolijidad el método es el siguiente:

```
boolean a = Arrays.equals(vector1, vector2);
```

Otra forma seria haciendo un metodo con un for dentro que recorra los 2 array y comparar posicion a posicion:

```
    Public boolean compararArrays(tipo vector1, tipo vector2)
    {
        boolean c = false;
        if(vector1.length == vector2.length)
        {
            for(int i = 0; i < vector1.length;i++)
            {
                if(vector1[i] == vector2[i])
                {
                    c = true;
                    if(c == false);
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    c = false;
                    break;
                }
              }
            }
          return c;
    }
```

utilice esto como prueba en el main:

```
int[] vector1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] vector2 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7, 8, 9 };
int[] vector3 = { 1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , 6, 7, 8, 9 };

boolean a= Arrays.equals(vector1, vector2);
boolean b= Arrays.equals(vector1, vector3);
boolean c = false;

System.out.println(a);
System.out.println(b);


for(int i = 0; i < vector1.length;i++)
{
    if(vector1[i] == vector2[i])
    {
        c = true;
        if(c == false);
        break;
    }
    else
    {
        c = false;
    }
}
System.out.println(c);
```

y arroja:

```
run:
true
false
true
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Answer (score 0):

quizá no sea la respuesta que estaba buscando, pero logre resolver de otra manera el problema que tenía, primero que nada elimine el array alarmasApagadas y en lugar de eso use un arrayList alarmasApagadas, y de esta forma ir añadiendo los id de las alarmasApagadas.
Lo segundo fue crear esta función:

```
public boolean buscarLista(int para){

boolean existe = alarmasApagadas.contains(para); /*Si el parametro mandado a esta función se encuentra
dentro del array este retorna TRUE*/

return existe;}
```

La función recibe como parametro el ID si el ID existe dentro del arrayList retorna true, en caso de que no retorna false.

Y ya por último use esta función, la cual se ejecuta cada 60 segundos para verificar si existen alarmas nuevas que aún no han sido apagadas:

```
 public void comparación() throws IOException, FileNotFoundException, InterruptedException, UnsupportedAudioFileException{    

  for (int i = 0; i < getNuevosID().length; i++){

    boolean encontrado = buscarLista(nuevosID[i]);
    if(encontrado){
    System.out.println("Esta alarma se encuentra apagada");
    }else{
        try {
            System.out.println("Esta alarma es nueva");
            play(); //Función que hace sonar la alarma.
        } catch (LineUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Principal.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        
        break;
    }
 }

}
```

De esta manera cuando encuentra una alarma nueva que no este dentro del arrayList "alarmasApagadas" la alarma suena, si todas las alarmas que me retorno mi búsqueda están dentro del arrayList "alarmasApagadas" significa que ya todas esas han sido apagadas, entonces no suena la alarma.